# How to write text into window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Parent form handle `hwnd` is existed. Now I want to populate it with `edit controls` into which output-text is written. I am not familiar with WIN32 API, Thanks for showing me some code examples. Thank you!~

Comment: This is very vague and broad. Consider purchasing a decent Windows API book and _reading_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546(VS.85).aspx

If you want to set text using chars then you can use `SetWindowTextA` so you don't need to bother with multibyte to/from wide characters.

I suggest the Programming Windows book by Charles Petzold.

You say hwnd is your parent then you could create the edit controls with default text like:

```
HWND hedit=CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"),TEXT("Default window text"),WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0,0,400,300,hwnd,0,0,0);
```

Read up on the docs for `CreateWindow` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create [Edit controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and do whatever you want with them.

Use google, etc or MSDN search before asking something.